# How can I repair a rusting dishwasher tray?

Tags: dishwasher

See the below image. Do I need to replace the entire tray, or is there some kind of fix I could do to the corroding area on the tray?

If I need to replace the entire tray, is this something that has a degree of standardization?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The racks in virtually all dishwashers are unique to the particular models from each manufacturer. In other words no standardization.

It is possible to imagine that it may be possible to clean up the rust and corrosion on the wires of the rack. Doing so would require removal of the plastic coating that covers the afflicted area. After you get it all cleaned up you would have to apply a new coating to the wires that would also bond to the rest of the existing wire coating.

It is possible to [purchase the plastic coating material](http://www.plastidip.com/home_solutions/ReRACK) specifically for this type of repair.

[image]

Comment: Going to give this a try. I'll post back here with the result. Thanks!

Comment: Only about a week into using the repaired racks, but so far so good! I used a bolt cutter to clip out the larger sections of rust, and a rotary tool with attached steel wire brush to sand off smaller areas. I then used the pictured product, applying liberally 3-4 coats. We'll see how it holds up in the longer term, but I'm optimistic.

Comment: I tried this, removing all rust and then applying this. Twice.  Rust recurred. I think this stuff just didn't stay on well enough.

At this point we are desperate. New racks are $420.  My wife is considering duct tape.

I suggested something like marine shrinkwrap tape. Or, if they make such a thing, high temperature shrinkwrap tape.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Correction: my wife did this (she's pretty good with this stuff but didn't peel back the vinyl beyond the rusted area) Do you need to peel back a section of the vinyl over the non-rusted section adjacent to the rust? and how much?

Comment: @maxedison Can you comment on how the repair held up now that it's 2 years later?

Comment: @AdamDavis It didn't hold up as well as I had hoped. I actually only continued to own the dishwasher/condo for about 9 months after my original post, and I imagine that another half year would have required me to do some touching up. Maybe I could have applied thicker layers to begin with? If you just have a couple small spots to coat, I'd recommend this product. But the cleaning of the corroded areas (what this post describes in the second paragraph) took me a long time because I had lots of rusting spots. If I were to do it all over again, I would just buy a new tray :)