# Repairing wire dishwasher racks

Tags: appliances, dishwasher, plastic, rust-removal, rust-proofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to repair (and is it worth the trouble to) a rusty dishwasher rack?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/how-to-repair-and-is-it-worth-the-trouble-to-a-rusty-dishwasher-rack)

We have a dishwasher with wire racks on the inside. The racks have a plastic coating on them, but after years of use, this has worn off in critical places. Now, rust is being deposited on the edges of our dishware. I'd like to clean off the rust and find some way to stop it, possibly by applying a new coating. I'm thinking of using a wire brush to clean off the rust and then applying some red RTV silicon gasket maker to replace the plastic coating. The color wouldn't match, but aesthetics don't really matter. Do you think this would work, or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/14518/5804

Comment: Yes, exactly. This should be closed as a duplicate. How does one go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered before with a good solution shown at this posting:

[How can I repair a rusting dishwasher tray?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20554/how-can-i-repair-a-rusting-dishwasher-tray/20555#20555)